# Is there a list / database of Chinese mathematical terms (for complex math)?

Tags: resources, terminology

Some things like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon) or advanced/graduate school math (like Group Theory, Ring Theory, Quantum Mechanics, etc.). Does Chinese have its own names for these types of things? If so, where can I find a big list of some sort, hopefully with English translations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be called 专业英语 in different area （it's for Chinese to learn English terms, but i think it will also help you） . For example, my bachelor degree is engineer, i used to learn "工程专业英语"。

I found this [site](https://badbrain2077.github.io/04-%E9%98%85%E8%AF%BB/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E4%B8%93%E4%B8%9A%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%8D%E6%B1%87/) and I hope it will help you.

If you want others, you can just search "XX专业英语" in baidu.com.

Answer (score 6):

the national academy for educational research, of taiwan  maintained files (pdf or excel) of bilingual terms, for mathematics, there’re five:

[數學名詞](https://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/301/)

[兩岸對照名詞-數學](https://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/320/)

[數學名詞-兩岸中小學教科書名詞](https://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/244/)

[數學名詞-兩岸數學名詞](https://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/404/)

[高中以下數學名詞](https://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/235/)

have fun :)

Comment: These don't import into my spreadsheet program on a mac, any ideas? https://imgur.com/a/iRAmZO5 The spreadsheets are blank when loaded into Google Spreadsheets as well.

Comment: @Lance, i do not have a mac os machine now, maybe try it on a window os?

Comment: @Lance Perhaps try LibreOffice? I've successfully viewed the spreadsheets on my Linux machine with it. Alternatively, try renaming `.xls` to `.html` (the file in your screenshot is mostly tag soup) and opening with a browser, then copying.